# Datasnap string parameters preceded by zero are trimmed of the zero

Tags: string, delphi, parameters, datasnap

I have a procedure in my DataSnap server that is triggered by a GET request and receives a single string parameter, but whenever the client sends a string value composed of any amount of zeros followed by any amount of numbers (i.e. 01, 002, 0047, etc), somehow the leading zeros are cut off, and I need those too.

I've been debugging Delphi hard trying to find where this happens, and if it happens server-side, but I haven't come across anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure those quotes actually are part of the string?

Comment: No, but I use QuotedStr() method to make it so for SQL

Comment: You verified (using a sniffer, Fiddler2 or similar tools) that the data on the wire (in the GET request body) is still ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the request that my client was making was somehow automagically being converted to integer whenever it "looked like" an integer, so now the value is being requested beween quotation marks so that it is converted to string, the way it should.

I feel kinda stupid for making such a big deal out of this.

Comment: It's actually a bug. Check this link: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=104535

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this forces REST into string handling mode:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = '0'+'1'
```

But I suspect either the single quotes should be double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = "01"
```

...or the quotes are not part of your SQL statement:

```
'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD = ''01'''
```

Comment: That was merely an example I gave of how the statement would look like in SQL, that is not the real problem. The real problem, I believe is that the parameter I receive is trimmed of preceding zeroes during the conversion from JSON to String type.